# I cannot install the Robotjs library in Node.js

Tags: python, robotjs

I cannot install Robotjs in Node. When I try to install the command: npm install robot-js, the screen shows this error:

```
        Error: robot-js binaries failed to install. You will need to install 
        them manually.
```

When I put the command: npm list robotjs, this message appears:

```
        ! - UNMET DEPENDENCY robotjs@0.4.5

        npm ERR! missing: robotjs@0.4.5, required by iamdinosaur@1.0.0
```

I do not know how to install manually and by npm is not installing

I have Python 3, I already unplugged it and left only Python 2.7, but nothing solved.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: This question likely did not get much attention because it was not appropriately tagged. I have created a new tag for `robotjs` and added the Python tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by downgrading the version of node.js 9, to version 6, with the binary module itself for the version, which is version 6.